# Firebase Functions - How to return a document snapshot from a cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### PROBLEM

Note: query is setted with this block of code:

```
let query = this.firestore
    .collection("films")
    .doc(filmId)
    .collection("casting")
    .orderBy("name", "desc"); // <---- DESC. ORDER

  if (startAfter) { <---- // TO AVOID STARTING AFTER NULL DOCS (which are at the bottom in descending order)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(startAfter, null, 2)); // IN THE SECOND CALL TO THE FUNCTION, THIS SHOWS THE REFERENCE TO THE LAST RETRIEVED DOCUMENT (in the previous call)
    query = query.startAfter(startAfter);
  }
```

I have a firebase cloud function which retrieve data (actors) from a collection of films. For the pagination, I am using the document reference, like this:

```
return query
  .limit(size)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
     const actorsNames = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.name);

     // Update the offset
     startAfter = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]; // <---- THIS

     return { actorsNames, startAfter };
});
```

As you can see, every time I retrieve N (=5) docs, I get the last doc's reference and update the offset for the pagination. Then, I send it back (the updated offset) to the client, who will call the firebase call function with this new offset as data if he wants to retrieve another amount of actors.

To avoid starting after null in desc order, I conditionally set the query like this:

```
let query = this.firestore
    .collection("films")
    .doc(filmId)
    .collection("casting")
    .orderBy("name", "desc"); // <---- DESC. ORDER

  if (startAfter) { <---- // TO AVOID STARTING AFTER NULL DOCS (which are at the bottom in descending order)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(startAfter, null, 2)); // IN THE SECOND CALL TO THE FUNCTION, THIS SHOWS THE REFERENCE TO THE LAST RETRIEVED DOCUMENT (in the previous call)
    query = query.startAfter(startAfter);
  }
```

The problem I am experiencing is that, in the second fetch, startAfter has the correct value, the last document retrieved from the pevious call, but for some reason, the query retrieve the same documents that the first one did.

### RESULT

**First call** (startAfter = null):

```
   -Resulted documents: [Tom Holland, Quentin Tarantino, Margot Robbie, Leonardo DiCaprio, Emma Watson] (EXPECTED RESULTS)
```

**Second call** (startAfter = reference to emma waton's document)

```
   -Resulted documents: [Tom Holland, Quentin Tarantino, Margot Robbie, Leonardo DiCaprio, Emma Watson] (AGAIN, THE SAME RESULTS)
```

I have no idea why is this not working as expected. In the documentation, the example for pagination with document ref is really similar (but with no orderBy desc).

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query

### EDIT

In both cases, I am performing the same queries.

->For the first fetch, on the client I do:

```
// (Ignoring error catching for simplity)
const response = await firebase.functions
  .httpsCallable("getActors")({ startAfter: startAfter.current}) // Currently, startAfter.current is null

// Update the startAfter cursor
startAfter.current = response.data.startAfter;
```

Then, in the firebase cloud function, I perform the query explained above and it returns this data [Tom Holland, Quentin Tarantino, Margot Robbie, Leonardo DiCaprio, Emma Watson] and, obviously, the updated startAfter offset.

->For the second fetch, I do the same:

```
// (Ignoring error catching for simplity)
const response = await firebase.functions
  .httpsCallable("getActors")({ startAfter: startAfter.current}) // But here, startAfter is a reference to the emma watson's document

// Update the startAfter cursor
startAfter.current = response.data.startAfter;
```

But for some reasons, it is returning to me the same data (same offset too) as the previous call.

### UPDATE

I have perform the same queries in the client side (without cloud functions) and all works good. Seems that the cloud function is not returning a DocumentSnapshot because of the data serialization. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `query` in your first query?  Please edit the question to be clear what exactly you're querying in both cases.  Also, I suggest not using JSON.stringify for logging arbitrary objects.  DocumentSnapshot objects have an API which will give you information that you can log.

Comment: The query is the same in both calls, but in the first call, startAfter is null. I will edit this to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries were good! The problem was that my cloud function serialized the DocumentSnapshot (as it is a complex object) before returning it to the client.

I have solved this issue setting an uuid to each document and then using it as cursor for my queries, instead of the document snapshot itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a bit we don't see here (how did you go from actorIDs to the actor documents?), but I will note the results you *show* are not ordered by name....

Comment: It is a simplified example of what I am getting on my real scenario, I forgot to order the ouput (updated), sorry. But the code is the same. Also, I am not going from actorIDs to the actor documents in this query (I mean, I am only touching one subcollection). In my subcollection of castings I have documents with the name of the actors (and other data) as fields. Each document represents an actor.